# What coding framework or system uses "$var=str_replace("{{thispart}}",$thisvar,"thisfile.html");"?

Tags: php

I am currently working on a project that connects to an API.

The previous developer created a structure for the code where the API is listed into a page using html files.

The files are loaded into the site using ajax.

The developer coded this:
The php file->

```
$var=str_replace("{{thispart}}",$thisvar,"thisfile.html");
```

The thisfile.html->

```
<div>{{thispart}}</div>
```

I have searched a lot on this and could not come up with a term for the search to find out what framework or system uses this.

What is this called? (framework/system/structure)?

Answer (score 0):

Seems your developer used [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade) template engine. Basically, with your existing code it does some string replace on the thisfile.html file with the `$thisvar` variables value using [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function.

Say,

```
$thisvar = 'fja3omega';
```

Then after,

```
$var = str_replace("{{thispart}}",$thisvar,"thisfile.html");
```

So your now `$var` variable now should contain this-

```
<div>fja3omega</div>
```

Comment: Its almost the same but it does not load any engine at all.  Its just one php file and one html file.  It does not connect to any other php source.

Comment: Then its just using simple variable replace with curly braces `{{variable_name}}`

Comment: I guess it must follow some kind of engine.  Going to search more on engines.  Its like laravel but without laravel